# Create record of Type B when record of Type A is created [JS, D365 Online]

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am trying to implement an 'on record creation' event, with the following scenario.

- User creates new record of type A
- Upon first save of that record, automatically create a record via JavaScript of type B

I tried to create an on change event for the 'created on' field, but got the following error.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdon").addOnChange(createOMTRecordUponCreatingPlan)
```

Error = Cannot read property 'addOnChange' of null

Comment: You'd preferably want to use a plugin for this and an event (or as D365 call is... a Step) alternatively a workflow could be used.

Comment: That's a solution I was thinking about... Everything else was done in JS, but good point!

Comment: Sadly, doing it via javascript on the form itself isn't a very reliable solution to go for. My personal go-to is an async step and a plugin.

Comment: @Adriani6 you should post it as answer, bcoz server side Plugin is the best practice :)

Comment: @ArunVinoth Didn't want to add a "one-liner" but added now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JavaScript to "detect" a record change on the form isn't the most viable idea as it'll not be reliable if the record is updated outside of the form window.

Your best choice is using a server-side plugin, here's a [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/tutorial-write-plug-in) on how to begin creating the project (it's much simpler than it looks).

You'll need (as you'll see in the tutorial) a Plugin Registration Tool - it's super easy to navigate around and create steps (events) for your plugins, you'll be looking for "Create" message for "Type A" entity.

Another alternative (might not be a possibility) is by using a [workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/administering-dynamics-365/dn531057(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).